# Text compression in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I know in SQL we can compress the text field like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE TableName (FieldName CHARACTER(255) WITH COMPRESSION);
```

I want to know how to achieve the text compression in Postgres.

Comment: For store the compressed string, see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2958073/287948

Answer (score 41):

Compression is enabled by default for all string types, you don't have to tell the database to do it. Check the manual about [TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/storage-toast.html)

- PLAIN prevents either compression or
  out-of-line storage; furthermore it
  disables use of single-byte headers
  for varlena types. This is the only
  possible strategy for columns of
  non-TOAST-able data types.
- EXTENDED allows both compression and
  out-of-line storage. **This is the
  default for most TOAST-able data
  types.** Compression will be attempted
  first, then out-of-line storage if
  the row is still too big.
- EXTERNAL allows out-of-line storage
  but not compression. Use of EXTERNAL
  will make substring operations on
  wide text and bytea columns faster
  (at the penalty of increased storage
  space) because these operations are
  optimized to fetch only the required
  parts of the out-of-line value when
  it is not compressed.
- MAIN allows compression but not
  out-of-line storage. (Actually,
  out-of-line storage will still be
  performed for such columns, but only
  as a last resort when there is no
  other way to make the row small
  enough to fit on a page.)

Comment: From the docs, it looks like TOAST compression is only active for values greater larger than 2kb.  The OP's example wouldn't hit the 2k threshold, and thus won't be compressed.

Comment: You can enforce compression, depends on storage parameters: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/storage-toast.html

Comment: By changing TOAST_TUPLE_THRESHOLD ?  I think that requires a recompile?

Comment: No, use ALTER TABLE: "Each TOAST-able data type specifies a default strategy for columns of that data type, but the strategy for a given table column can be altered with ALTER TABLE SET STORAGE."

Comment: SET STORAGE is effectively a noop for rows smaller than 2k though, right?  "The TOAST code is triggered only when a row value to be stored in a table is wider than TOAST_TUPLE_THRESHOLD bytes (normally 2 kB)"

Comment: It appears to me, from the docs, that if a row is > 2KB and any of its columns are TOAST-able then TOAST will try and compress, then store out of band, TOAST-able columns until it reaches TOAST_TUPLE_TARGET for the row.  So recompiling with different parameters would be the only way to force compression for < 2KB rows.